# Spark plug wires arcing when car is cold

Tags: sparkplugs, mitsubishi

Around one month ago I have replaced my spark plugs and respective wiring. Everything was fine to until one week before, when the car started to misfire (struggle?) in the morning when car is cold. I checked the wires right after starting the vehicle and I felt electrical shocks, so I guess the wires are arcing. When I run about 5 kms, the problem goes away. The question is: what should I do to make it run smoothly from the start? I guess it might be caused by accumulation of the moisture during night(since it is parked outside).

The car is Mitsubishi Lancer 1.3 GLX '99.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try greasing the outside of the plug leads with dialectric (silicone) grease.  This is standard procedure when servicing certain Citroen vehicles.

Comment: Oke, thanks for advice, makes sense. Going to buy silicone grease today and try to report the results tomorrow morning.

Comment: Good luck!  Hopefully it does the trick and if so is a nice, low cost solution.

Comment: It may also be worth mentioning that Q20 (the original WD40) was created specifically to address this problem.

Comment: @Juann Strauss I actually do have WD40 at home. But it is spray.. I am not sure how to apply it without spraying too much on metallic parts.

Comment: Liberal amounts of WD40 sprayed all over the outside of the plug leads will, at least temporarily, have a similar effect as silicone grease.  You won't damage anything by spraying it with WD40 so it's well worth a try next time your car is cold, slightly damp and hesitant to start or run smoothly.

Comment: Although I could not find silicone, WD40 done its job, car started smoothly today.. Going to try the silicone after it ships. Thanks.